# Dql mutation add duplicate records

Tags: dgraph

### What I want to do

Prevent the dql mutation to add duplicates records

### What I did

I add a graphql schema:

```
type Product {
    id: ID!
    name: String! @id @dgraph(pred: "Product.name")
    slug: String! @id @dgraph(pred: "Product.slug")
    image: String @dgraph(pred: "Product.image")
    created_at: DateTime! @dgraph(pred: "Product.created_at")
    updated_at: DateTime! @dgraph(pred: "Product.updated_at")
}
```

the above graphql schema has generated the bellow **DQL schema:**

```
<Product.created_at>: datetime .
<Product.image>: string .
<Product.name>: string @index(hash) @upsert .
<Product.slug>: string @index(hash) @upsert .
<Product.updated_at>: datetime .
<dgraph.drop.op>: string .
<dgraph.graphql.p_query>: string @index(sha256) .
<dgraph.graphql.schema>: string .
<dgraph.graphql.xid>: string @index(exact) @upsert .
type <Product> {
    Product.name
    Product.slug
    Product.image
    Product.created_at
    Product.updated_at
}
type <dgraph.graphql> {
    dgraph.graphql.schema
    dgraph.graphql.xid
}
type <dgraph.graphql.persisted_query> {
    dgraph.graphql.p_query
}
```

I run a mutation to add some data using: https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgo#running-a-mutation.
But it does not respect the `@id` added to the schema to some fields like "slug" and "name".

Using the graphql mutation this is working and respect the uniqueness by returning an error:`"message": "couldn't rewrite mutation addProduct because failed to rewrite mutation payload because id aaaa already exists for field name inside type Product"`

```
dgraph version v21.03.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dql you have to handle this by your own using [Upsert Block](https://dgraph.io/docs/mutations/upsert-block/).

Or if you don't want the power of dql you can use the graphql which handle this stuff automatically.